# import json file produced from _search to elastic search using shell script

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, bulk

I have generated json in ElasticSearch by running a range query and it generates in following format :

```
{
  "took" : 63,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1000,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "0",
      "sort": [0],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":0,"balance":16623,"firstname":"Bradshaw","lastname":"Mckenzie","age":29,"gender":"F","address":"244 Columbus Place","employer":"Euron","email":"bradshawmckenzie@euron.com","city":"Hobucken","state":"CO"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "bank",
      "_type" : "_doc",
      "_id" : "1",
      "sort": [1],
      "_score" : null,
      "_source" : {"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
    }, ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to import this json back to ElasticSearch.  I have seen the _bulk api from elastic, but it needs a different json format.  Could anyone help me out here?

How can I change this file to proper json file using shell so that i can dump this json file to ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what specifically you are trying to do.. but from what you have described you should look at the `_reindex` API instead.  It will allow you to send the results of a query into a new different index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

They show this an example where you provide a query:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter",
    "type": "_doc",
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "user": "kimchy"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ryan, thanks for the response , but i want to copy the data from the json file to the same index , can i do it using _reindex by replacing dest index to source index ? or there is other way around?

Comment: Is your goal to update the original records, or just to duplicate them?